# document not defined javascript error (works in Chrome console but not in integrated terminal of editor)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and I like to test my console.logs or my javascript using the integrated terminal in VSC. I have node.js installed and I use the 'node .' command to test run my javascript. I get this error

console.log(document.getElementById("para").textContent);
                                                                          ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

I am just testing some stuff.
[My html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtbg.jpg), 
[javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf88Z.jpg)

However, when I test my code through the chrome console, it works for me. No document not defined error or anything. Can anyone assist me on this?
Thanks !

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post the actual code instead.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById("para").textContent)` should be in your frontend code not on backend

Comment: Sorry I am new in stackoverflow. thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document` Only exists in the browser. If you are trying to just run your Javascript directly without the accompanying browser, this will fail.

The same also goes for the `window` object, these are both only available in the actual browser environment. This is the reason this works in the chrome console, as you are on a webpage and have access to these objects.